# Postman create class

Tags: javascript, postman

My goal is really simple. I would like to create a class named Helper to store all common data/methods for my collection.

This is how I planned to do :
[image]

In the main pre-request Script this is the code :

```
var HELPER = pm.globals.get("HELPER");

console.log(HELPER.mandatory);
console.log(HELPER.checkIfEmpty());
```

I'm able to retrieve the mandatory variable but I cannot call checkIfEmpty

I get the following message:
`TypeError: HELPER.checkIfEmpty is not a function`

As you can see, this method exist.

I checked this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_function) but without success ...

Do you have any idea what I missed ??

Comment: Probably `pm.globals` stores JSON data, not objects with prototypes and methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to manage what I expected :

[image]

and the main pre-request Script code :

```
console.log(helper.mandatorySubIssues());
console.log(helper.checkIfEmpty("Hello World"));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is basically what I am doing right now. Add to this [feature request](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/10009) if you would like to support the feature request.